# KDE: disable super_L (windows key) key shortcut as menu launcher

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, start-menu, kwin

Where can I disable `super_L` key (windows key) opening KDE menu?

Or where can I change this shortcut?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In KDE Plasma 5.8, the super/win key is also used to trigger the launcher, when pressed and released without combining it with another key. To disable the feature,

1. put this into `~/.config/kwinrc`:

   ```
   [ModifierOnlyShortcuts]
   Meta=
   ```
2. then reload the window manager (kwin), either by logging out and logging back in, or with with this command:

   ```
   qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin reconfigure
   ```

Equivalently run this

```
kwriteconfig5 --file kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Meta ""
```

Sources:

- Initial announcement of the feature https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2016/08/modifier-only-shortcuts-available-in-plasma-5-8/
- An answer from Reddit
  https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/55udc1/how_do_i_stop_the_meta_key_from_opening_the/d8epzzj/
- Plasma tips on KDE's own wiki, with further tips for Latte Dock users https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Tips#Windows.2FMeta_Key

Comment: Addition: configuration should be reloaded after that. To reload configuration, run `kwin_x11 --replace` or just log out and log in.

Comment: Addition: `kwriteconfig5 --file kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Meta ""` command can be used instead of editing the config file manually.

Comment: Confirmed working in KDE Plasma 5.18.5 on Manjaro. (Just in case someone thinks it's outdated because the answer is from 2016.)

Comment: Confirmed to work in Kubuntu 22.04, using command from @Sasha you don't need to logging back.

Comment: still working 2023, arch linux / KDE plasma. Thanks for solution, this was a major annoyance