# broken keyboard subsystem in KDE, is it possible to switch to another strategy?

Tags: linux, kde

I'm a devel, I need to use shortcuts a lot. I don't know what kde does where and how with keyboard, but there is something wrong. Stuff which works on multiple different desktop variants, seems to have problem here.

I will describe 2 usecases, and [b]my question is[/b], if it is possible to somehow to switch to different subsystem of how kde treats keyboard input, which might behave better. I don't need to use two-part shortcuts (actually how to disable that?), I need correct functionality.

usecase 1: If I use default us layout and launch xev, pressing alt produces alt and pressing enter produces enter. However, only in KDE, if I launch idea and try to press alt-enter combo, nothing happens. If I try to re-assign this combo, java process detects meta+alt+enter. META WASN'T PRESSED though. Why it is passed into java process?

usecase 2: We will use custom layout here(again, worked for 10+ years on multiple platforms)

my keyboard layout uses:
include "level3(ralt_alt)"       //right alt is right alt actually
include "level3(win_switch)"  //both window key is level3 key
include "level3(menu_switch)"  //menu key is also level3 key

and this key definition:

```
key <AB03>  { [         c,          C,       Escape,     NoSymbol ] };
```

and just this thing creates surprising stuff. On isolevel3 on char c, there is escape defined. It works, but if I press ctrl-c nothing happens! Why? No idea, but there is global shortcut ctrl-escape which causes conflict. If I remove ctrl-escape global shortcut, ctrl-c will work again. BUT! I didn't (for love of god) press ctrl-escape, I pressed ctrl-c (and that xev dude saw that, he would confirm). I'd undestood this behavior if I'd press ctrl+iso3+c, but not this, so I really have no idea, why ctrl-escape global shortcut kicks in. Another example. Lets say, that I defined Esc as global shortcut, for say system shutdown shortcut when leaving office. If I press c now, nothing happens! Why? Again, because level3-c could theoretically produce escape if pressed(which it wasn't), and we have global shortcut for it, so letter c 'cannot' work, for some reason. This is 'ritial' issue for me!

Can we somehow fix this? Switch to different keyboard handler strategy or ...?

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally not sure, but I tried to remove from `~/.config/kwinrc`:

```
[ModifierOnlyShortcuts]
Meta=
```

which was added as recommended in [KDE: disable super_L (windows key) key shortcut as menu launcher](https://superuser.com/questions/1156130/kde-disable-super-l-windows-key-key-shortcut-as-menu-launcher).  This removal seems to 'fix' the issue with java processes. The stuff with global shortcuts is unaffected by this.